# WinForms ALT key beep

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have an application in which I have implemented some keyboard shortcut keys for a given set of operations, some of these use <kbd>ALT</kbd> as a modifier e.g. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.  The functionality itself works fine however the system beeps during the key press.

I have read various posts that say I could use e.Handled in the KeyPress event however this is not helping in my scenario.  The problem is easily replicated by creating a new Windows Forms application and running it without any modifications, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> for example will cause the system to beep.

I have noticed that other application such as Notepad have this behaviour too, if you launch Notepad and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (or any other invalid menu keypress) the system will beep.

Is there any way to prevent the beep via my application or is it standard Windows behaviour?

Comment: I think it's meant to alert the user that she is selecting an undefined menu shortcut. You might try adding _hidden_ menu entries with these shortcut defined.

Comment: It's standard Windows behaviour.  If you look in Control Panel --> Sounds for an sound effect named 'Menu Command', that's what plays.  The current sound scheme I'm using (one of the Windows 7 supplied ones) just has that sound effect blanked.  If you want to remove it just for your PC, then I suggest modifying in Control Panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can Handle KeyDown Event and do something like this for Alt+1 But i suspect you might have to do this for all the invalid keys

```
private void keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D1 && e.Alt)
   {
       e.Handled = true;
       e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use SuppressKeyPress in you KeyPress event management?

```
 e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

Comment: I have tried setting the forms KeyPreview to True and added breakpoints to the KeyDown, KeyPress and KeyUp events and the beep occurs before entering any of them.

Comment: Ok I will try to make the same code to see if I found a solution

Answer (score -1):

I use Alt+E for editing a record under certain circumstances.
Here's what I had to do to eliminate the beep.

```
private void Object_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E && e.Alt)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}

private void Object_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.E && e.Alt)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        EditRecord();  // This opens a form for the editing process
    }
}
```

> **Note**: If you try to use EditRecord from Object_KeyDown and only SuppressKeyPress in Object_KeyUp, you will still get the beep.

Comment: Your code can't work. You can't have 2 `Object_KeyUp` functions.